# CSS background getting darker after animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

So I have this strange issue that I have never seen before. I am just creating something simple with HTML/CSS/JavaScript, but for some reason during text fade/slide transitions, the background color keeps getting darker/lighter in Chrome. It's a very subtle color change, but definitely noticeable. During transitions, the color is somewhere around #181818, and after it's done it turns to the normal set value of #101010. I tried to take a screenshot of how the page looks, but in the screenshot the colors look completely normal. So then I tried viewing the webpage in Safari and Firefox. Completely normal. I only notice this happening with dark gray colors.

Has anyone experience this in Chrome before, and if so, is there an easy fix? Below is the code I am using.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');

let index = 0;
let previous = 0;

const toggleText = (index, state) => {
  if (state == 'show') {
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      if (i == index) {
        sections[i].querySelector('.text').classList.add('show');
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      if (i == index) {
        sections[i].querySelector('.text').classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

toggleText(0, 'show');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (index > 2) return;

  toggleText(index, 'hide');
  index++;

  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
      toggleText(i, 'show')
      sections[i].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  }
});

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (index < 1) return;

  toggleText(index, 'hide');
  index--;

  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
      toggleText(i, 'show')
      sections[i].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif, 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #101010;
  color: white;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 1.5s .5s;
}

.text.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<main>
  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>This is the first page.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>This is the second page.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>This is the third page.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Title 4</h3>
        <p>This is the fourth page.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="prev">Previous</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

If not, maybe it's my monitors... not sure. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: latest chrome and win 10, hd monitor , bg color remains the same. Idem with other browers. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Not seeing a problem on Chrome (or Edge) on Windows10 fairly recent and decent laptop.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus appreciate the input guys. I am using my Mac for coding, transferred the files over to my Windows Desktop (which use the same monitors) with no issues. Maybe something with the USB-C to DisplayPort cable I'm using. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't anything in the code!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing it in your code snippet either, also using the latest chrome, on a rather-new MacBook Air with the brightness turned all the way up.  But maybe if it really is happening on your side, a `will-change: opacity` on .text could help?

Comment: No luck, but I transferred the files from my Mac to my Windows Desktop (using the same monitors) and the issue doesn't transfer. Maybe has to do with the USB-C to DisplayPort cable I'm using, not sure. As long as the code is good I'm not too worried about it